# Why serilog not logging to file?

Tags: serilog

```
"WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/Error/applog.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [Thread:{ThreadId}] [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

I have this in my app setting.json file?

Why serilog not writting to    "path": "Logs/Error/applog.log", ?

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
.Build();

```
        var Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
          .CreateLogger();

        Logger.Information("Hello, world!");
```

I have this setting file ?

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Serilog": {
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "File",
          "Args": {
            "path": "Logs/Error/applog.log",
            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [Thread:{ThreadId}] [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
            "rollingInterval": "Day",
            "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "HrSoultion": "server=.;database=Maqta;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that "Serilog not writing to path ..."? Are directories created but file is not? Is the file created but is empty? Are there any errors?

Comment: I have logs folder and I am doing 
        Logger.Information("Hello, world!");

Comment: Did you make sure to check the self log, like [the documentation suggests](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog)?

Comment: @VladDX I did man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration in `appsettings.json` doesn't seem to be correct.

If you provide this configuration, it should work:

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/Error/applog.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [Thread:{ThreadId}] [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My result:

[image: Result]

---

For reference, I used .NET 6 and these NuGet packages:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Links:

- https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file